# How to use the mouse wheel in LibGDX?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm trying to allow the player to zoom the camera in and out using the mouse wheel, but I can't find any methods that interact with the mouse wheel. Is it possible to use the mouse wheel with LibGDX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to create a class that implements the InputProcessor interface ([javadoc link here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html)). It contains a method called "scrolled", which I believe is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @John's answer, after you implement a custom inputprocessor, you can implement the `scrolled` function only, and then use an inputMultiplexer with any currently available one like so:

```java
InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(myScrollProcessor);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stageMain);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```